# Len function returning zero to variable

Tags: excel, vba

Stuck on an issue with code below, using F8 step, the Len function picks up a value, but does not
put it in the Lresult variable, not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```vb
Function lastrownum(lrbook As String, lrsheet As String, lrcolumn As String, charnum As Long)
    
    'for any workbook/sheet/column looks from bottom up for character amount greater than specified (charnum)
    
    Workbooks(lrbook).Sheets(lrsheet).Activate
    
    Dim tbbrows As Long, tbhrows As Long
    
     Dim lngRow As Long
     Dim lngRows As Long
     
      lngRows = Range(lrcolumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     
      Dim Lresult as long
     For lngRow = lngRows To 160 Step -1
    Lresult = Len(Range(lrcolumn & lngRow).Value)
     If Lresult > charnum Then
     lastrownum = lngRow
     GoTo endloop
     End If
     Next
    endloop:
    
End Function
    
Sub tesit()
    MsgBox lastrownum(reportfile, "BANT AJEs", "C", 6)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of passing a workbook name and a sheet name, pass a worksheet *object* and then make sure to fully qualify all `Range` calls against that worksheet.

Comment: Instead of `GoTo endloop`, use `Exit Function`.

Comment: Your code works for me.  (although it could do with a lot of cleanup)

Comment: Maybe yo do not have a value on column C which length is bigger than 6? And you should try to send `reportfile` parameter as string.

Comment: And although your method seems to work for all workbooks, there is a value `160` that is probably workbook specific.

Comment: Sorry, didnt include my worksheet data, I know it needs cleanup, and it does run on some worksheets, but for the one in particular, it reads a 26 character cell, but does not enter it into the Lresult variable, when you F8, you see the value in the Len function as 26, but for some reason it wont pass over. But everything else everyone said is true, it could use cleaning, I can use exit, 160 is because the sheets will not get that large, but the fact remains that it wont pass a cell with 26 characters that Len identifes into the Lresult variable.

Comment: Function lastrownum(lrbook As String, lrsheet As String, lrcolumn As String, charnum As Long) As Long

'for any workbook/sheet/column looks from bottom up for character amount greater than specified (charnum)

Workbooks(lrbook).Sheets(lrsheet).Activate
Dim tbbrows As Long, tbhrows As Long, lngRow As Long, lngRows As Long
 
 lngRows = Range(lrcolumn & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastrownum = 0
 For lngRow = lngRows To 160 Step -1
 If Len(Range(lrcolumn & lngRow).Value) > charnum Then
 lastrownum = lngRow
 Exit For
 End If
 Next

End Function

Comment: There is no error with your script for me. I only sent the workbook's name as a string. Are you sure that you use this script? Because I'm not sure.